# c# Cefsharp (like chromium) don't show videos on facebook

Tags: chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I can not see the videos on the facebook website with cefsharp.

Debugging sees this error:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: The manifest specifies content that cannot be displayed on this browser/platform.

What could be the problem? 
Many thanks, 
Matteo

Comment: Due to licensing issues default builds do not support proprietary codecs like H264, sites like Netflix/Twitter/Instagram/Facebook won't play video/audio.

Comment: where can I find a build that supports proprietary codecs like H264? thanks

Comment: You have to obtain the licences and then build `CEF` yourself.